# jQuery MLKeyboard Won't Disappear When Click Outside on Another Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this jQuery [MLKeyboard](http://mbut.github.io/jquery.mlkeyboard/).

JS

```
$('input#example-1').mlKeyboard({layout: 'en_US'});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="example-1" class="col-md-12" placeholder="Try"/>
```

As usual, when I click the textbox `#example-1` the keyboard appear. I'm trying to click outside (document/body), the keyboard is disappear. Until this, it working good.

Now I'm trying to add 1 textbox with different id `#example-12`.

```
<input type="text" id="example-12" class="col-md-12" placeholder="Try"/>
```

and the JS:

```
$('input#example-1, input#example-12').mlKeyboard({layout: 'en_US'});
```

When I'm trying to click the textbox `#example-1` the keyboard is appear then I click outside, the keyboard is disappear.

When I'm trying to click the textbox `#example-12` the keyboard is appear then I click outside, the keyboard **IS NOT DISAPPEAR**.

My question, why the keyboard on textbox `#example-12` is not disappear when I click outside?

Answer (score 1):

It is not disappear because thy have issue with the library itself..u can see the same error on the demo page 
http://mbut.github.io/jquery.mlkeyboard/

raise an issue here.
https://github.com/mBut/jquery.mlkeyboard/issues

i tried with jquery but it not working correctly so try some other plugin

Comment: Perfect... Cheers

Comment: But wait, when I click the keyboard key on virtual keyboard, the keyboard directly disappear